# Veutify - cannot align v-img and v-text perfectly centered one top of the other inside v-card-title

Tags: html, css, vue.js, layout, vuetify.js

For a login component, I am trying to place an image and text perfectly centered with the image above the text inside my `v-card-title`.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see the they are not aligned perfect center in relation to each other. I have tried a lot of different ways to achieve this but nothing has worked.

Here is the code:

```
<v-card-title class="aca-login-title">
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <v-flex xs12 md12 lg12>
      <v-img mx-auto max-width="2.5em" class="login-avatar" src="imgUrl"/>
      <v-text style="color:#565656">Some Title Here</v-text>
    </v-flex>
  </div>
</v-card-title>
```

The `<div class="text-xs-center">` was suggested on another answer and, although it aligned the image correctly, it doesn't work for the text.

I also added the `mx-auto` from another suggestion, but it hasn't fixed the problem either.

I am relatively new to Vuetify layouts/classes so forgive me if this is a simple thing to do. Any guidance on how this can be done is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can align the elements with the flexbox helper classes `d-flex` and `flex-column`. You can read more about that in [Vuetify's documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/).

In your case it would look like this:

```html
<v-card-title class="aca-login-title d-flex flex-column">
  <v-img
    max-width="2.5em"
    class="login-avatar"
    src="imgUrl"
  />
  <v-text style="color:#565656">Some Title Here</v-text>
</v-card-title>
```

I removed the `div` and `v-flex` elements as they aren't necessary to achieve the desired result.